# jQuery - Select/unselect multiselect options with replacement divs

Tags: jquery

I'm working on a modal multiselect replacement that takes a `<select>` element and replaces it and it's `<option>`s with divs.  I am a jQuery novice, and I've reached a point now where I have the replacement working perfectly but with a few hiccups in the functionality.

The desired functionality is as follows:

1. You click **"Choose Your Options"** which creates a modal dialog
   containing a list of `div.option`s which have been populated using
   `.text()` from each `<option>`.
2. When you choose an option from the modal, it applies a class of
   `.selected` to the `div.option` selects the corresponding `<option>`
   and appends the `.text()`of that option to an `<li>` inside a `<ul>`
   outside of the modal.
3. When you click on one of the newly generated `<li>`s, the `<li>`
   itself should `.fadeOut();` and `.remove();` while making the
   corresponding `<option>` unselected.
4. **IF** you click "Choose Your Options" after this point, you should be able to select/unselect `<option>`s and have it reflect accordingly in the `<ul>`.

As of now, everything happens correclty except for step 4.

**I've included my code here: [jsfiddle.net/zumwalt/HB7HJ/](http://jsfiddle.net/zumwalt/HB7HJ/).**

Once again, I'm very novice at jQuery/js, so I'm positive that I've taken some steps in creating this that don't make sense.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Step 4 seems to work for me in FireFox.  What browser are you using?

Comment: Nevermind, after closer inspection it looks like your UL on the main page is clearing out when you click "Choose your options" for the second time.  Is that what the issue is?

Comment: You might want to look into [Chosen](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) and how they're doing it, sounds similar to what you're looking at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a couple of issues in your js. I updated your fiddle, check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7HJ/13/

The first thing I did was to remove this two lines:

```
$('ul.multiselect-dropdown-options-'+name+'').empty();
$('div.option', multiselectmodal).removeClass('selected');
```

They were removing selected items when calling the modal. I believe we don't want that :P

Then I checked if your option was selected or not, adding the option if not, and removing it if did:

```
if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
    $('ul.multiselect-dropdown-options').append('<li class="dropdown-option drop-down-option-'+value+'">'+optiontext+'<a class="remove-option">x</a></li>');
} else {
    $('.drop-down-option-' + value).fadeOut().remove();
}
```

I also took the following js out from where it was (Inside a click() function, didn't make much sense):

```
$('.dropdown-option-'+value+'').click(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(500, function () { $(this).remove(); });
    option.removeAttr('selected');
    $('div.option-'+value+'').removeClass('selected');
});
```

I'm giving a second look to your code right now, I think it might be improved a bit, i'll update this if I find something. Anyway, not bad at all for a newbie :D

**Edited after second look :P**

My previous fiddle failed when deleting a row :( I set a new working fiddle up: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7HJ/15/

I refactored the code to make it, imho, a bit more understandable. As Jack the Ripper would say, let's go by parts:

1. Removed from the js the HTML that could positively be in the HTML (And added it to the HTML :P).
2. Removed some unused stuff, like the scroll thing and some useless variables. Maybe you need that in your application, so be careful. Anyway, since that's not the point of the answer, it just messes the code up.
3. Added the option value as the id of `.option`s and `.dropdown-option`s. We'll need them later to check wich option is clicked.
4. Took the `click()` events (Modal and options stuff) out from the loop, I think it's clearer that way. That's why we need the ids on the options.
5. Tweaked the `.option`s and `.dropdown-option`s `click()` event so it will get the id and add/select/remove/unselect the right option according to that id.

And I think that's all. I'm sure this code can be vastly improved, but I tried to respect yours so it'd be easier to understand, and I believe it might work as a working base. Let me know if you have further questions :)

Comment: This is awesome and works as it should.  Just to explain why I made some of the decisions regarding the html, scrolling and whatnot: the application of this script is for a kiosk with no keyboard.  The form is created by a form builder that I don't have access to change (though I'm going to try) and spits out a simple `<select>` tag, hence the HTML insertions.  The scrolling is there in the case that the number of options exceeds the height of the page.  If it doesn't, the multiselect will not be in a modal window.  All that being said, I may have to re-add the html insertion and scrolling.

Comment: Jeez, "kiosk with no keyboard" sounds harsh :P Yep, you'll probably need to, but hopefully it won't conflict with the current code. Good luck with the app!

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you are adding the following markup:

```
<ul class="multiselect-dropdown-options multiselect-dropdown-options"></ul>
<div class="multiselect-dropdown">Choose your options</div>
```

using jQuery.  I see that you were including `-'+name+'` for the last class in the UL, but I can't see a reason to do this.

I went ahead and pulled this out of your jQuery and put in your HTML and the page appears to work fine now.

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7HJ/12/

Looking at your jQuery, it appears you are adding quite a bit of HTML through code.  Is there any reason that it can't just be static?

Hope this resolves your issue!