# How to select and unselect a li item using jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

Here i am selecting a li item in a list and changing the border of that li item but if i select another li item the border of the currently selected item is changing but the previously selected li items border color has to change to the original color

Here is my code

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#list3 li").click(function () {
            $("list3 li.clicked").removeClass("clicked");
            $(this).addClass("clicked");
            $(".clicked").css("border", "3px solid red");

        });
  });
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: How about rather than setting inline styles using `.css()` you just add the CSS properties you want to change to the `clicked` class definition?

Comment: I think the following links could give you the answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857781/best-way-to-unselect-a-select-in-jquery
and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8452277/jquery-select-unselect-multiselect-options-with-replacement-divs

Comment: @Dubious Did you read this question or any of the ones you linked? They're not asking similar things at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with less code. Write like this:

```
$("#list3 li").click(function () {
            $("#list3 li").removeClass('clicked');
            $(this).addClass('clicked');

        });
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/q4qR8/1/

Comment: it is working fine..i have tried it for mouseover like $("#list4 li").mouseover(function () {
            $("#list4 li").removeClass('mouseover');
            $(this).addClass('mouseover');

        });

Comment: it is also working but when i leave the mouse from list1 to list2..the last mouseover li item has that border.how to remove that border while traversing from one list to another list

Comment: But i recommend you can achieve this without JS check this http://jsfiddle.net/q4qR8/3/

Comment: how to select multiple li items using control button?

Answer (score 1):

Add a CSS definition for the class `clicked` to the external CSS file for your page or inside a `<style>` tag, like so:

```
.clicked {
    border: 3px solid red;
}
```

That way the CSS handles the styling for you, and the border should automatically revert to its previous state once you remove the class.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#list3 li").click(function () {
            $("#list3 li").css("border", "none");
            $(this).css("border", "3px solid red");

        });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#list3 li").click(function () {
    $("#list3 li.clicked").toggleClass("clicked");
    // if you don't want to be able to deselect the li that is already selected
    // add this 
    // if (!$(this).hasClass("clicked")) {
      $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
    // }
 });
});
```

and css style rule:

```
.clicked {
  border: 3px solid red;
  ... extra customization
}
```

Comment: it is working fine..i have tried it for mouseover like 
        $("#list3 li").mouseover(function () {
            $("#list3 li.mouseover").toggleClass("mouseover");
            $(this).toggleClass("mouseover");

        });

Comment: .mouseover {
  border: 3px solid blue;
  it is also working but when i leave the mouse from list1 to list2..the last mouseover li item has that border.how to remove that border while traversing from one list to another list

Comment: @bala3569 you need to handle the mouseout event also

Comment: how to select multiple li items using control button?

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#list3 li").click(function () {
            $("list3 li.clicked").css("border","0");
            $("list3 li.clicked").removeClass("clicked");
            $(this).addClass("clicked");
            $(".clicked").css("border", "3px solid red");

        });
  });
```

Alternatively, you can put the border property in the .clicked class itself.

Answer (score 1):

The line:

```
 $(".clicked").css("border", "3px solid red");
```

Doesn't update the styling of "clicked" it only changes the styling of the selected element(s) i.e. `$(this)`.

You'd be better adding a css rule for .clicked:

```
.clicked {
    border: 3px soild red;
}
```

And removing the original line from your javascript thus:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#list3 li").click(function () {
        $("list3 li.clicked").removeClass("clicked");
        $(this).addClass("clicked");
    });
});
```

Then the styling changes will happen automatically using the addClass() and removeClass() functions.